# Dynamically display django form multiple times

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django formset to get display django form few times to get information from user. But here the number of times I can display form is fixed. Is there any good way to get display form dynamically, once the user enter the details then display same form again to get more information without refreshing the page. Below is the code currently I'm using.

in models.py

```
class Tiers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,default=None, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    tier_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank = True) #name of the tier
    tier_value = models.IntegerField() #Can only be in exact dollar amount
    tier_benefits = models.CharField(max_length = 5000, blank = True) #creators explain what the donor benefits for each tier
```

in forms.py

```
class TierForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['user']
        model = models.Tiers


TierFormset = modelformset_factory(models.Tiers,form=TierForm, extra=2)
```

in HTML page

```
<!-- {% extends "base.html" %} -->
{% load bootstrap3 %}

<!-- {% block content%} -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Update Your Profile</h1>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_formset formset %}
    <input type="submit" class='btn btn-default' value="Update Profile">
  </form>
</div>
<!-- {% endblock%} -->
```

Currently I'm displaying form 2 times but I want to display several depends how tiers user want to use. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use some javascript code to add/remove forms to formset. Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/django-formset-bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks @art06. I'll test this and update here.